# Android dynamic list view to different screens?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-tabs

List elements and tabbed-panel contents are populating from json file.
When I click **A** element in listview1 it has to go to tabbeddpanel(above).

When I click **B** element in `listview1` it has to go to `listview2` screen and when I click **B1** element in `listview2` it has to go to tabbedpanel(below).

Help me in doing this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the data set passed to your `listview1` so that you can add a tag here.

For example, the data set you're passing in your `listview1` is an `ArrayList` of tis object.

```
public class myData {
    private String content;
    private int tag;    // Add a tag attribute to handle them differently in the list.
}

// Here's the list passed to your `listview1` 
private ArrayList<myData> myDataList = new ArrayList<myData>();
```

Now inside your `bindView` function check for the `tag` of the object of that position and handle the action differently like this.

```
if(myDataList.get(position).getTag() == 0) {
    // Do this
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .Got it.

Comment: Used only tag variable.Not bindView function.